# Inequality for Characteristic Function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

For a **discrete distribution** the characteristic function $|\psi(u)|=1$ for other values of $u$ than $0$. We also know that  $|\psi(u)|\leq 1$.

How does this imply that for a **continuous distribution** we need to have $|\psi(u)|\leq e^{-c}$ for some $c>0$? Why $e^{-c}$?

**Edit**
I forgot to mention that the above condition is satisfied for $|u|>T$, for some large "T". That is the condition is of the same type as $|\psi(u)|=o(|u|^{-n})$ for $|u|\to \infty$ showed in Lemma 4, Ch XV.5 of Feller-"An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications" Vol 2.

The result is used in proves related with the remainder for expansions of density functions(See Gnedenko- "Limit distributions for sums of independent random variables" p.229 for example)

Comment: Who claims that this is true? Note that $\psi(0)=1$ holds for any characteristic function $\psi$. Therefore, we cannot expect $|\psi(u)| \leq e^{-c}$ for $c>0$.

Comment: Please see my latest edit. Sorry for missing a very important part of the condition.

Comment: Do you mean $e^{-cu}$ instead of $e^{-c}$?

Answer (score 0):

When the density $f$ is of class $C^1$, this follows from an integration by parts.

For the general case, we may approximate $f$ in $\mathbb L^1(\mathbf R,\lambda)$ by a $C^1$ function.